# Hadoop cluster. Data is automatically replicated across the cluster data nodes

Tags: hadoop

1. In a Hadoop Cluster, is the data automatically replicated across the data nodes or it must be programmed?
2. If it must be programmed, then how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

1. The default value of `dfs.replication` is 3. This is present in your [`hdfs.site.xml`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) configuration file. This means that when you setup your hadoop cluster, it is automatically configured to replicate each block thrice.
2. It can be changed using the following ways:

   - You can change the value of  `dfs.replication` in your `hdfs-site.xml` and set it to an integer you'd like (1 means no replicas)
   - You can pass the replication factor as a per-file value using the command [`setrep`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#setrep) :

     `hadoop fs -setrep -w 3 /user/hadoop/file.txt`

     This will replicate `file.txt` 3 times.

Comment: As I have already mentioned, you have to set that value in your `hdfs-site.xml`. Once that is set to 3, you need not do anything in your JAVA program.

Comment: thank you, how i can use "hdfs-site.xml" in program java for configured to replicate each block thrice please ?

Comment: No, that is a configuration file. Hadoop is configured according to that. And since you will be running the wordcount jar using `hadoop jar`, those configurations will already be taken into account.